# How do I find the Max and Min values of a row that my if statement has been applied to?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, max, min

So I was given this yesterday and this works brilliantly but I have been asked to bold the minimum and maximum value on the row that my function below has been applied. I have 3 different datasets with different values on different rows, so I can't just ask it to bold row 7. I need to demonstrate that this can be applied to any given data. Does anyone know how to achieve this, my data is between C3:W16 for all 3 datasets to save confusion.

```js
function searchOutput() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getRange("C3:W16").getValues();
  data.forEach(function (row, i)
  {row.forEach(function (cell, j)
   {if(cell >= 5 && row[j + 1] < 5){sheet.getRange(i + 3, j + 3, 1, 2).setFontWeight("bold")
   {if(cell Math.max(...row)).getRange(i + 3, j + 3, 1, 1).setFontWeight("bold")
   {if(cell Math.min(...row)).getRange(i + 3, j + 3, 1, 1).setFontWeight("bold")}}}})})

}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: what if there are multiple maximums and minimums? for example let's say the maximum value in the row is 10 and you have two 10s. You want to bold them both ?

Comment: yes, but as the function runs along the columns, I need it to find the maximum first and then the minimum. If the minimum is before the maximum, then the data represented will mean that the power output this data represents will not work.

Comment: it is very confusing to me unfortunately. Can you provide a sample input and expected output? it does not have to be the full range. Just provide a screenshot of 3x3 dummy cells and show us the expected output. A picture is worth a thousand words

Comment: There you go, so my function that you see is making the value that is >5 and <5 bold, as that represents that the power output is On (5 or more) and Off (4.99 or less). So I need to Bold the Max and Min values (5.33 and 4.33), the second image is another dataset with this function being applied to different rows due to the values its searching for.

Comment: You can easily find the max or min of a row using [`Math.max(...row)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) and [`Math.min(...row)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min). The spread syntax [`...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) will automatically map the contents of the array as arguments to those functions. You can then loop over the items of the row, check for equality with the min or max and update the formatting of the cell.

Comment: Is it really as easy as that? I didn't use the  `...` but how would it be written within my script?

Comment: It is, but I left out a few details. You'll need to get not only the values for the range but the font weights as well via [`getFontWeights()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFontWeights()). That will help simplify your code a bit. Take a crack at implementing it yourself. If you stumble I'll help to point you in the right direction...

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting for this? Using GAS should *always* be your last resort.

Comment: okay, thank you. I'll give it a try

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk makes a good point...Is there a compelling reason to use a script?

Comment: I'm a university student learning computing science, this is my first year. None of what I have shown you 'needed' to be scripted but I want to teach myself so as I am a curious individual. We were taught the basics but our lecturer said that we will not learn all of this till next year, but I am impatient and I whilst I am still curious, I would like to learn how to do all of these statements and functions :)

Comment: @TheAddonDepot I have been attempting this and so far I haven't seemed to have moved anywhere? I made edits to the question above

Answer (score 1):

There's a 3-step approach to optimally processing multiple rows:

1. Fetch arrays of values, formatting or other state from the sheet using a bulk getter method.
2. Process and update the fetched arrays.
3. Write the updated values, formatting or other state back to the sheet using a bulk setter method.

This is necessary b/c invoking sheet methods like `getRange()` and `setFontWeight()` multiple times within a loop is computationally expensive.

So the first thing you need to figure out is which bulk getter and setter methods are applicable to your use case.

In your scenario you need to find the min and max of values in a row so [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) is a must have. And you want to update the font weight of those cells so [`getFontWeights()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getFontWeights()) and [`setFontWeights()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFontWeights(Object)) are also necessary.

> **TIP** *If you need to find a getter or setter method for other resources check out the documentation for the [`Range`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) object. The general rule is that any method with `get` or `set` as its prefix and ends in `s` is a bulk getter or setter method.*

Now that you know what you need, its fairly simple to write the code:

```js
function boldMinMax() {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("C3:W16");
    
    // fetch array of arrays of row values and array of arrays of font weights in bulk using getter methods
    var valueRows = range.getValues();
    var fontWeightRows = range.getFontWeights();
    
    // process fetched arrays updating font weights for min and max cells
    valuesRows.forEach(function(valueRow, rowIndex) {
        
        // Only need to calculate min and max once per row
        var min = Math.min(...valueRow);
        var max = Math.max(...valueRow);
        
        // find and update fontWeightRow
        var fontWeightRow = fontWeightRows[rowIndex];
        
        valueRow.forEach(function(value, cellIndex) {
            if (value === min || value === max) {
                fontWeightRow[cellIndex] = 'bold';
            }
        });
    });
    
    // Write updated font weights back to sheet
    range.setFontWeights(fontWeightRows);

}
```

That should be enough to get you sorted.